# How minify html, css and js in keystone js

Tags: keystonejs

How minify html, css and js in keystone js

Which build tool used in keystone js?

Where is the config needs to add for build tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own build tools like you can integrate gulp in keystone and define different task like build, test and dev. Run those task as needed. For begining you should visit this [link](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/) to know how to configure gulp in your project.